# Postfix: relay domains except some addresses

Tags: postfix, mail-forwarding

I'm relaying emails for a bunch of domains to another server via the `relay_domains` configuration in `main.cf`:

File /etc/postfix/relaydomains:

```
domain1.com OK
domain2.com OK
domain3.com OK
...
```

Now I need to relay just a few addresses to another server:

```
mail1@domain2.com
mail2@domain2.com
```

All other should be forwarded as now. This means:

```
*@domains1.com -> server1
*@domains2.com -> server1
*@domains3.com -> server1
mail1@domain2.com -> server2 not server1
mail2@domain2.com -> server2 not server1
```

How can I do this? What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use postfix transport :

Set up `/etc/postfix/transport` as a transport map lookup table:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

With the following content :

```
 
 domains1.com relay:[server1.example.com]
 domains2.com relay:[server1.example.com]
 domains3.com relay:[server1.example.com]
 mail1@domain2.com relay:[server2.example.com]
 mail2@domain2.com relay:[server2.example.com]
```

http://flylib.com/books/en/2.262.1.59/1/